# distribution of two floating point multiplication

Tags: numerical-methods

given any two floating numbers on a PC. what is the distribution of the roundoff error of their multiplication?

Using math

let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be two floating numbers, the true value of their multiplications is $x=x_1 x_2$, the number represented on a PC is $\hat{x}$.
What is the distribution of

$$
\frac{|\hat{x} - x|}{|x|} \text{?}
$$

## [update]

let's set the range of $x_1$ and $x_2$ as
$$
x_1, x_2 \in [1E-5,\ 1E+5]
$$

Comment: How can you answer this without knowing the distribution of the roundoff of the factors ?

Comment: The word distribution is normally used in the context of stochastic variables. Even after the edit it is not clear what you mean.